# Multiple pathdef files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, path

Suppose two different Matlab users share a computer and they each want to be able to save and load their own Matlab paths.  (Or, a single user wants to use different paths at different times.)  What's the easiest way to handle this?

Should there be multiple pathdef files?  Alternatively, should they each have a script that calls [restoredefaultpath](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/restoredefaultpath.html) and then uses [addpath](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) to add new paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`startup.m`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file for that.

When starting up, Matlab executes the file `matlabrc.m`, which is the master startup file, and is common for all users. Among other things, this file

1. Sets the first entry of the path as the user-folder of the *current* user, that is, the user that started Matlab. (This is done by calling `pathdef`,  which in turn calls [`userpath`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html)); and then
2. Looks for a `startup.m` file in the path, end executes if it exists.

Therefore you can place a user-specific `startup.m` file in each user's folder, and Matlab will run the appropriate file *depending on which user* started Matlab. In that file you can set the path on a per-user basis, and do other user-related stuff.

Comment: Thanks.  How does Matlab know which user started Matlab?  Does Windows tell Matlab who the current Windows user is?

Comment: `matlabrc` calls `userpath`, which does exactly that job. On my system, `userpath` has a line `p = system_dependent('getuserworkfolder')` that does the actual job. I don't know how it works. But yes, it must essentially ask the OS